# Tela modal não fecha após pesquisa no IFrame dentro dela

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp

Resolvi abrir esse post, pois o mesmo é continuação de um post que eu fiz, porém com a seguinte diferença. A pesquisa que eu estava tendo dificuldade de fazer a partir de uma tela Modal com IFrame em ASP, agora funciona. A questão agora é que a tela Modal não fecha após a pesquisa, mas a pesquisa funciona, pois se eu fecho o Modal manualmente, funciona. Veja abaixo o código, que o colega TobyMosque me ajudou a fazer(méritos dele).

```
function selecionar(num_contrato, cod_ts_contrato, nome_entidade){
<%if trim(strAction) = "" then %>
    //ABRIU POPUP
    var janela = null;
    var isIFrame = false;
    var isPopUp = false;        
    if (window.dialogArguments) {
        isPopUp = true;
        janela = window.dialogArguments;
    } else if (window.parent.opener) {
        isPopUp = true;
        janela = window.parent.opener;
    } else if (window.parent.frameElement) {
        isIFrame = true;
        var documento = window.parent.frameElement.ownerDocument
        var janela = documento.defaultView || documento.parentWindow;
    }

    if (janela) {
        var form01 = janela.document.form01 || janela;
        var cod_ts_contrato_id = "<%= trim(txt_nome_campo_cod_ts) %>" || "cod_ts_contrato";
        var num_contrato_id = "<%= trim(txt_nome_campo_cod) %>" || "num_contrato";
        var nome_contrato_id = "<%= trim(txt_nome_campo_desc) %>" || "nome_contrato";
        var funcao_executar_id = "<%= trim(funcao_executar) %>";
        var indsubmit = "<%= lcase(indsubmit) %>" === "true";

        var ocod_ts_contrato = form01[cod_ts_contrato_id];
        var onum_contrato = form01[num_contrato_id];
        var onome_entidade = form01[nome_contrato_id];
        var ofuncao_executar = funcao_executar_id ? janela[funcao_executar_id] : null;

        if (ocod_ts_contrato) ocod_ts_contrato.value = cod_ts_contrato;
        if (onum_contrato) onum_contrato.value = cod_ts_contrato;
        if (onome_entidade ) onome_entidade .value = nome_entidade;
        if (typeof ofuncao_executar === 'function') ofuncao_executar();

        if (indsubmit) {
            form01.submit();
        } else if (onum_contrato != null && onum_contrato.disabled==false && onum_contrato.enabled==true) {
            onum_contrato.focus();
        }
    }

    if (isIFrame) {
        janela.fecharModal();
    } 

    if (isPopUp) {
        parent.self.close();
    }

<%else %>
    //ABRIU NORMAL ENTAO DAR SUBMIT
    document.form01.cod_ts_contrato.value = cod_ts_contrato;
    document.form01.num_contrato.value = num_contrato;
    document.form01.action = '<%Response.write strAction & "?PT=" & Request("PT")%>';
    document.form01.submit();
<%end if %>
}
```

Aqui está o código na tela pai(chamadora do modal).
Código para fechar o Modal

```
var fecharModal = function () {
        var dialog = $(janela.document.getElementById("dialog"));
        dialog.dialog("close");
    }
```

Código para abrir o Modal(criar)

```
var dialog = $("#dialog1");
var openModal = $("#btnLupa");
var frame = window.frameElement;

dialog.dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
});

dialog.load(function () {
    dialog.dialog("open");

});

var AbrirModal = function (url, title, width, height) {
    dialog.attr("src", url);
    dialog.dialog("option", "title", title);
    dialog.dialog("option", "width", width);
    dialog.dialog("option", "height", height);
}
```

Com todos esses códigos esse é o erro que dá: Não reconhece janela. Se declaro assim: `var janela = null;` e sigo o código como está, dá esse erro:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of null

Se copio a declaração de janela na função selecionar e colo na função de fechar, continua dando esse erro.
No aguardo.

Comment: Deu certo assim: var fecharModal = function () {
        var dialog = $(document.getElementById("dialog1"));
        dialog.dialog("close");
    }

Comment: Gostaria de dar o mérito ao colega TobyMosque pelo esforço e empenho em tentar me ajudar.